# ngmodel multiple bindings for one form field angular

Tags: angular

While doing a code review I came across this line

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="studentInfo.student.full_name" 
        [(ngModel)]="studentInfo.person.full_name" 
         type="text" name="Name" #name="ngModel" />
```

I was surprised that this actually works. Both the fields in the object get the data. Is this just a coincidence or is it designed to work like this ?.

Comment: What is the `value` of input in this case

Comment: The [()] is two way binding. If both studentInfo fields have values, which ends up in the input box as the default? The second one? Or are they always the same value?

Comment: In this case they are both same value, full name of the person. The reason name is duplicated is that student object and person object goes to different microservices.